# How to edit command line in full screen editor in ZSH?

Tags: zsh, editors

In bash, using vi mode, if I hit <kbd>Esc</kbd>,<kbd>v</kbd>, my current command line is opened in the editor specified by `$EDITOR` and I am able to edit it in full screen before 'saving' the command to be returned to the shell and executed.

How can I achieve similar behaviour in zsh? Hitting <kbd>v</kbd> in command mode results in a bell an has no apparent effect, despite the `EDITOR` environment variable being set.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

See `edit-command-line` in `zshcontrib`.

```
bindkey -M vicmd v edit-command-line
```

Comment: (Just to clarify): To enabled the `edit-command-line` “widget” you will need something like `autoload edit-command-line; zle -N edit-command-line` in one of your *zsh* init files (see the [ZLE Functions section](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#SEC283) of the [`zshcontrib` documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html)).

Comment: How do you activate this once it's in place? The bindkey in the emacs-style answer makes sense to me. But I can't find reference on what `bindkey -M vicmd v` sets up.

Comment: @MatSchaffer Same as Bash: if you are in vi mode, then hit `<ESC>` to enter command mode from insert mode and and then `v` to visual mode (`Meta-v` is the same), or just `v` if you're already in command mode.  If you're using Emacs mode, the typical binding is `C-x C-e`.

Comment: Remapping the v key means you can't use visual mode any more, so I prefer remapping to the spacebar (which doesn't do anything useful in normal mode) with `bindkey -M vicmd ' ' edit-command-line`

Answer (score 67):

In case you prefer Emacs keybindings:

```
autoload -z edit-command-line
zle -N edit-command-line
bindkey "^X^E" edit-command-line
```

Comment: The `^x^e` binding seems to be a default with [current .oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/9650861e56a3404313adc35cbcb1f32a7015b99d/lib/key-bindings.zsh#L65), which is extremely nice.

Comment: ^x^e is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Similar setup for Prezto as long as the `editor` module is loaded.

Comment: Can someone edit the answer to explain why the second line is necessary, especially with `-N` flag?

Answer (score 46):

You can use `fc` to edit the last command in history. It's not the same as editing the same command, but a quick hit on the Enter key makes your current command the last command in history.

Comment: This is great when you are ssh'ed into some other machine which does not have `edit-command-line` setup as one may have in their personal environment.

Comment: what does fc stands for? f-command...?

Comment: This is almost certainly what you want. Just about any time your command is complex enough to want to edit it, you've already tried a few different variations of it so it's in your history. To add on to this, you can use `fc $ENTRY` to edit that command in your `history`. `zshbuiltins(1)` has more info. And, then, when it works, you can use `fc` again to save it to a file to run later as a script!

Answer (score 32):

This is the complete configuration that I added to my `~/.zshrc` to get the same behavior from bash:

```
export VISUAL=vim
autoload edit-command-line; zle -N edit-command-line
bindkey -M vicmd v edit-command-line
```

Comment: Per the earlier comments, this is configured by default if you're using [Oh my ZSH](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) or [Prezto](https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto). The latter requires the `editor` module to be loaded and `vi` or `vim` selected for command mode.

Comment: I'd vote to make this the accepted answer, it solved my question with all configuration described. Thanks.

Comment: For me, `v` should surrounded by quote: `'v'`.

Comment: but I lost my cursor after existing vim

Comment: @roachsinai, if `v` were a special character in the syntax of `zsh`, you'd need `bindkey -M 'v'icmd 'v' edit-command-line` and `export VISUAL='v'im` but of course `v` is not special in the syntax of zsh or any shell for obvious reasons, so the quotes are superflous. They'd only be needed if you had something like `alias -g v=gotcha` in your `~/.zshrc` (and no `alias -g "'v'=ahah"`)

Comment: this works as expected with `zsh 5.9 (arm-apple-darwin22.1.0)`. hooray for proper full screen command line editing!

Answer (score 1):

In case you're like me wanting to emulate oh-my-zsh behaviour that is to open the current line in vim when you press 'vv' in normal mode, use the following :

```bash
autoload -Uz edit-command-line
zle -N edit-command-line
bindkey -M vicmd 'vv' edit-command-line
```

Answer (score 1):

I think @quodlibetor's comment is worth an answer on its own:

If you are using .oh-my-zsh, the default key compination is:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>