# Execute a command in zsh vim mode

Tags: vim, zsh

In `zsh` in `vim mode`, I write something

```
foo foo bar bar
```

Then I hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> to go in normal mode and type  <kbd>:</kbd>

```
foo foo bar bar
execute: _
```

Then, I assume I can do that, I want to search and replace `bar` with `baz`

```
foo foo bar bar
execute: s/bar/baz/g_
```

Then I try to hit Enter, but that doesn't work. I can only go back from the `execute` using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.

How can I execute the command?

I tried this with my normal `.zshrc` and without any `.zshrc` at all.

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't seem to answer your question of how you do a substitute command in zsh vim mode. @pfneusel, did you ever find a way to do exactly what you have above?

Comment: @jspencer No, I would type `v` and enter `vim`, if I want to use the substitute command.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[The `vicmd` mode](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#Keymaps-1), despite the name, is for Vi's normal-mode commands. The prompt started by `:` isn't for Vi's ex-mode commands, but for running [ZLE (Zsh's line editor) commands](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Editor-Functions-Index.html):

```
$ echo foo
execute: e_
edit-command-line          emacs-forward-word         end-of-history             end-of-line-hist           exchange-point-and-mark    execute-named-cmd          expand-history             expand-or-complete-prefix
emacs-backward-word        end-of-buffer-or-history   end-of-line                end-of-list                execute-last-named-cmd     expand-cmd-path            expand-or-complete         expand-word
```

Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> will work when a unique prefix has been entered (i.e, say you type `ed`, which matches `edit-command-line`, then <kbd>Enter</kbd> will work). You can press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to see matching commands.

Comment: Thanks. A reason for using `bash` then instead of `zsh`.

Comment: @pfnuesel it is? Does Bash support using Vi's ex commands?

Comment: Typing `v`, you can enter `vim` and do whatever you can do in `vim`.

Comment: @pfnuesel Oh, that. Zsh has that. It's not enabled by default. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/6622/70524

Comment: @muru Your answer is a bit misleading. What you’re referring to as the “vicmd mode” is in fact the `command` keymap — that’s the “ex-like” one that gives you the `execute:` prompt for entering ZLE commands. The `vicmd` keymap *is* for working vi(m)-style command mode. When using zsh in vi mode, you’ll likely be swapping back and forth between `vicmd` and `viins` in much the same way that you move back an forth between command and insert mode in vi(m).

Comment: @wjv I'm used to calling it normal mode. I hear command mode and I think command-line mode. I rephrased that part.