# Setting new key bindings in ZSH removes default ones

Tags: zsh, keyboard-shortcuts, zle

I've added following code at the end of my `.zshrc`:

```
export VISUAL=vim
autoload edit-command-line; zle -N edit-command-line
bindkey -M vicmd v edit-command-line
```

When I restart the shell, it works perfectly but all previous key bindings stop working.

I'm unable to search history (**CTRL-R**) and I'm unable to move in command line (**CTRL-A/E**) for example.

Maybe I placed these commands in the wrong place?

Any help, very appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set `VISUAL` to a string containing `vi`, zsh uses the Vi [keymaps](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#Keymaps) (`vicmd`, `viins`, …) with Vi-style default key bindings. Otherwise zsh uses the `emacs` keymap with Emacs-style default key bindings.

If you want to use Emacs-style command line editing in the shell but use Vim as your favorite editor, add [`bindkey -e`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-bindkey) to your `.zshrc`.

If you want to use Vi-style command line editing, but with some bindings from the Emacs-style defaults, you'll have to define these bindings yourself. `^R` in Emacs mode runs [`history-incremental-search-backward`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-history_002dincremental_002dsearch_002dbackward) which isn't bound in Vi mode. The default key bindings for search in Vi command mode are `/` for [`vi-history-search-backward`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-vi_002dhistory_002dsearch_002dbackward) and `?` for [`vi-history-search-forward`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-vi_002dhistory_002dsearch_002dforward). To move to the beginning or end of the command line, you have `0`, `^` and `$` as usual.

Comment: `bindkey '^R' history-incremental-search-backward` restores `CTRL-R` (not `CTRL-A/E`). Adding `bindkey -e` works but I lost the ability to invoke `vi` using `ESC-V`. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your time.

Comment: @gsscoder What do you want to do? You can't both have all Vi bindings and all Emacs bindings: they're sometimes contradictory. To edit the current command with your editor, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6620/how-to-edit-command-line-in-full-screen-editor-in-zsh

Comment: This made perfectly sense. The problem I was lacking a basic concept... Now I understand. Thank you

Comment: I want to explain that I wanted to use `vim` as editor and just keep `CTRL-A/E` to move directly in terminal. I've achieved it with this two commands: `bindkey '^A' beginning-of-line` and `bindkey '^E' end-of-line`. In https://gist.github.com/gsscoder/6466d661e66b09131f9c0d0945e386d5 it's possible to see all commands I add to my `.zprofile`.